# MY SQL how to find the minimum for each year with subquery and innerjoin

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Currently, I am trying to write a subquery to find the minimum aggregate salary for each year and the corresponding team ID.

I thought of writing a subquery to inner join a data table where it has columns year ID and min aggregate salary on the year ID with the original data table.

While trying to figure out the code for the subquery, I first decided on how to subquery. My proposed code and output are below

```
SELECT 
    yearID, teamID, sum(salary) AS aggregate_salary
FROM Salaries 
GROUP BY yearID, teamID
HAVING min(aggregate_salary)
ORDER BY yearID, aggregate_salary ASC;
```

| yearID | teamID | aggregate_salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1985 | SEA | 4613000 |
| 1985 | MIN | 5764821 |

The table above continues until year 2016.
Now i'm thinking how do I inner join this such that I only isolate the minimum aggregate_salary for each year. so there would only be 1 salary which is the minimum for each year.
I initially thought of the code below, but i was simply just throwing back the same output at myself.

```
SELECT 
    y.yearID, y.teamID, y.aggregate_salary
FROM (SELECT s.yearID, s.teamID, SUM(s.salary) AS aggregate_salary
        FROM Salaries as s
        GROUP BY s.teamID, s.yearID) AS x
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
    s.yearID, s.teamID, sum(s.salary) AS aggregate_salary
FROM Salaries as s
GROUP BY s.yearID, s.teamID
HAVING min(aggregate_salary)) AS y 
            ON x.aggregate_salary = y.aggregate_salary;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You cannot refer to output alias of one outp[ut column in the expression for another column. You must use expression instead of alias... But aggregate functions cannot be nested - your need seems to be illogical or errorneous.

Comment: Please post table definition (run `show create table Salaries`) and some sample datea

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need in

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT yearID, 
                     teamID, 
                     sum(salary) AS aggregate_salary,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY yearID ORDER BY SUM(salary)) rn
              FROM Salaries 
              GROUP BY yearID, teamID )
SELECT yearID,
       teamID,
       aggregate_salary
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

?

Comment: What did you change? how does this improve the query? Code only answers are not great at explaining anything.